# What is the purpose of Deprecation?

Tags: java, programming-languages

Is it just giving different names to previously named method? Does it change with the language you use? Is it essential? I have noticed different APIs having deprecated methods, which actually seem easier to use.

Comment: What research have you done on the topic?

Comment: Have you at least [read the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) on the subject?  If so, what concepts were difficult or confusing?

Comment: You might have a more successful question if you [edit] to focus on why deprecated methods seem easier to use.

Answer (score 8):

It usually means that any code marked as deprecated is considered old and out of date, or it may have potentially serious issues with performance/conformity to standards/platform-specific issues/security/compatibility/etc..., and that there is probably a better replacement. It is marked as deprecated to indicate that developers writing new code should avoid that deprecated code, but it is left in the API so that old code that was written before the code marked as deprecated will still function without needing to be re-written.

Comment: It's also sometimes used as a warning. In SQL Server, for instance, Microsoft will deprecate code two or three versions ahead of its obsolescence, giving developers time to switch over to a newer method before the old one goes away.

Comment: @mgw854: Interesting: Microsoft will *remove* previously deprecated code? I guess I spend a lot of time in Java where most libraries will just leave deprecated code so as not to break older systems.